# placeOrder Mutation does not return order number

Tags: magento2, checkout, graphql, place-order

So I am using the magento graphql api to go through the cart workflow. I am using the braintree payment method. Everything goes smoothly until I use the placeOrder mutation. It returns the error saying

Unable to place order: A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again

According to these docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/mutations/place-order.html that means

The shopper tried to place an order when no products are in the shopping cart.
However I know this is false because I fetch and log the cart details before the placeOrder mutation. The cart details are below.

```
{
    "id": "9CDxLEFLMBDdbdqdDKk6oVPoeE32ZNVi",
    "email": "abennett@redacted.com",
    "items": [
        {
            "product": {
                "uid": "MzYw",
                "sku": "mask-child-1",
                "name": "Kids' Face Mask",
                "price_range": {
                    "minimum_price": {
                        "regular_price": {
                            "value": 18.5,
                            "currency": "CAD"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": 360,
                "__typename": "SimpleProduct"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "id": "69",
            "__typename": "SimpleCartItem"
        },
        {
            "product": {
                "uid": "MzYx",
                "sku": "mask-adult-1",
                "name": "Adult Face Mask",
                "price_range": {
                    "minimum_price": {
                        "regular_price": {
                            "value": 18.5,
                            "currency": "CAD"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": 361,
                "__typename": "SimpleProduct"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "id": "70",
            "__typename": "SimpleCartItem"
        }
    ],
    "shipping_addresses": [
        {
            "firstname": "Antonio",
            "lastname": "Bennett",
            "company": "Redacted",
            "street": [
                "Redacted"
            ],
            "city": "Redacted",
            "region": {
                "code": "ON",
                "label": "Ontario"
            },
            "postcode": "Redacted",
            "telephone": "Redacted",
            "country": {
                "code": "CA",
                "label": "CA"
            },
            "available_shipping_methods": [
                {
                    "carrier_code": "cadstd",
                    "carrier_title": "Free Standard Canada, This shipping method is not trackable",
                    "method_code": "cadstd",
                    "method_title": "Canada Post (3-9 business days). Please allow an additional 1-2 weeks for production."
                },
                {
                    "carrier_code": "cadexp",
                    "carrier_title": "Express Canada, Tracked",
                    "method_code": "cadexp",
                    "method_title": "Canada Post (1-4 business days). Please allow an additional 1-2 business days for production."
                },
                {
                    "carrier_code": "cadpri",
                    "carrier_title": "Priority Canada, Tracked",
                    "method_code": "cadpri",
                    "method_title": "FedEx (1-2 business days). Please allow an additional 1-2 business days for production."
                }
            ],
            "selected_shipping_method": {
                "carrier_code": "cadexp",
                "method_code": "cadexp",
                "carrier_title": "Express Canada, Tracked",
                "method_title": "Canada Post (1-4 business days). Please allow an additional 1-2 business days for production."
            }
        }
    ],
    "billing_address": {
        "firstname": "Antonio",
        "lastname": "Bennett",
        "company": "Redacted",
        "street": [
            "Redacted"
        ],
        "city": "Redacted",
        "region": {
            "code": "ON",
            "label": "Ontario"
        },
        "postcode": "Redacted",
        "telephone": "Redacted",
        "country": {
            "code": "CA",
            "label": "CA"
        }
    },
    "selected_payment_method": {
        "code": "braintree"
    }
}
```

The kicker as well is that although the placeOrder mutation returns that error, I am able to see the order in the admin with a status of payment processed. Any Ideas??